# Blender 2.8 translate vertex using scaling

Tags: modeling

In previous versions of Blender I could translate vertices to the same coordinate as the cursor by enabling cursor transform orientation, selecting vertex to move, pressing S to scale, type the coordinate I wanted to translate along (X, Y or Z) and typing 0. The vertex would move to the same coordinate of the cursor (zero scale relative to cursor). This feature doesn't seem to work in Blender 2.8, or is there a way to enable this?

Comment: There is no much difference here between 2.7x and 2.8x versions. What specific action causes difficulty?

Comment: As I asked before, scaling with cursor transformation doesn't move a vertex. It does in 2.7. It does not in 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Double check this. Scaling in 2.8x works similar to 2.7x:

[image]

if you still have problem with it, provide more information and screenshots.

Comment: It does not work for me. I have imported my configuration from blender 2.7. I must have something not configured.